# Adding an external HTML block inside a Django block

Tags: html, django

I'm developing a Django webapp, I created the layout.html and extended to all the HTMLs. Now, i need to take a `<main>` block and put on another file, because the same block is used twice in the project. As far as I know, I can't make a `{% load static %}` inside an already extended file `{% extends 'layouts/layout.html' %}` .

I tried with the `<div data-include="path/file.html"></div>` and with the

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#load_home").on("click", function() {
        $("#content").load("content.html");
    });
});
```

and also using `<iframe>` but nothing. I guess the problem is that I'm using a custom script, and it must necessarily be paired with the HTML block using it. Any other ideas? I can't stand repeating code snippets...

Comment: You **can** use `{% load static %}` inside an extended template though, don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: Plus you can further use [extends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#extends) on already extended templates and you can also [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#include) other templates

Comment: am struggling a bit in doing this but... i'll try again (because i already tried). i'll update the post with my answer in case it works, crediting you.

Comment: error I'm getting: 'extends' cannot appear more than once in the same template.... Told ya

Comment: Yes of course you cannot extend multiple template in one (how would that even work?). But you can have something like `grand-parent-template` < `parent-template` < `child-template`.

Comment: the problem is: I somehow cant both load static and extend... don't ask me how. seriously. parent template will not fix, this is not what i need

Comment: still unresolved.